# Uniqueness of an Integral eq.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I’m trying to solve

$$\int_0^1|(t^2 - at -b)|\,dt =1/12$$

for $a$ and $b$.

I got one solution when $a=1$ and $b=-1/4$, how I can prove that solution is unique?!

Comment: Is that the absolute value of $t^2-at-b$? If so, you'll need to consider the values of $t$ such that $t^2-at-b < 0$

Comment: Yes, it’s the absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not unique. Try $a=1$ and $b=-7/64$ for example. There are even other solutions with different values of $a$ and $b$!

Comment: Any idea to finding the other solutions form?!

Comment: I don't think the equation will look that nice. In order to evaluate $a$'s and $b$'s exactly, you'll have to split up the integration into parts where $t^2-at-b$ is positive and parts where it is negative. You can probably do that integration out on your own if you really need to.
The general idea is just integrate it then solve for $a$ and $b$ after setting the resulting expression equal to $1/12$

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but shouldn't the range of $t$ must be between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @PradyumanDixit Yes, it should. I don't think I said otherwise anywhere. Did I?

Comment: No, I was just proposing a way to see the problem a bit differently and maybe this point could help.